# Transmit an internet connection over wireless

Tags: wireless, digital-communications

My target is to transmit an internet connection (8 Mbit/s) over long range wireless RF (7.7 km) with LOS (Line Of Sight).  I live in a country where there is no rules for RF transmission, so i can use anything I want.  3G is not suitable due to price, speed, and reliability concerns.Also i can't use any repeaters in between, nor can i use directional antenna.However, i can use other communication protocols such as xbee.I also would like suggestions on what equipment and protocols  to use.

I'm looking for suggestions of where to start in putting together such a link.

Comment: Which country is this that doesn't have any rules for RF transmission? I don't believe you.  I expect you're making this up to avoid people telling you that you shouldn't do this.  One way or the other, this smells like you are trying to get away with something, and then trying to hide it.

Comment: Why can't you use directional antennas?

Comment: the wind is too powerful for them to stay in the same angle at a distance of 8 km

Comment: The [NTRA](http://www.tra.gov.eg/english/main.asp) might not agree with you there.

Comment: It is just on paper.  We can do whatever we want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In principle, this is very simple - use wifi with a pair of directional antennas. 10s of kilometers are possible.

The details matter. Instead of a wifi card with a built-in antenna, you need a card with a cable connector, followed (possibly) by a booster amplifier, terminating in an antenna.

Google on wifi range extenders and similar phrases. While this site does not provide detailed buying recommendations, radiolabs.com is a good place to start for overall ideas.

Answer (score 2):

You can build a pair of Cantenneas, which are very cheap and can potentially reach >10km under ideal LOS conditions...

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DJCgsBaqxWQ

You can also buy commercial equipment designed for this exact use. I've used these and they are relatively cheap and work...

[https://www.amazon.com/Ubiquiti-Nanobridge-NB-5G25-Outdoor-25DBI/dp/B004MYZ8U2/ref=as_sl_pc_ss_til?tag=joshcom-20&linkCode=w01&linkId=XWQHYKMNK4DXO7PC&creativeASIN=B004MYZ8U2](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004MYZ8U2)

Alternately you could also use relay stations along the path to extend the reach, although this will be more expensive and have slower performance.

Comment: what is the most powerful WiFi router/booster you know

Comment: @ahmedeshra shopping questions are off-topic as per the help centre.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to a high gain [omnidirectional](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B006JPSSF4) antenna,you can also add a WiFi booster amplifier.  WiFi signals in the US are limited to 100 mW, but you apparently are not restricted to that.  [This one](http://www.teletronics.com/amplifiers24ghz5wattout.html) is 5W. Select 5W under the second drop down list.  There are also 1W and 2W amplifiers available.

[image]